# blender2.8 gltf export for three.js with bumpmap or normalmap or roughnessmap?

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf, bump-mapping

I saw some discussions saying gltf does not export bumpmap but if I look into my exported gltf file (separate files mode) there is a bumpmap file with a bumpscale (and also normal map). After loading into three.js I get a meshstandard material with bumpmap object and scale value and also normalmap object. But they seem to have no effect on the rendered object. What is exactly allowed to do to export relief effect from Blender to Three.js with gltf ?

Answer (score 2):

The only relief effect available in glTF is a tangent-space normal map, [as shown here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/import_export/io_scene_gltf2.html#normal-map):

[image: normal map example]

Blender does have the ability to convert height maps and other kinds of bump maps to tangent-space normal maps, by way of the "Bake" function in Cycles.  There are also online utilities that can do this as well.